# Angular.js - can't inject external module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to make the simplest possible website setting, where I have an Angular.js app with single module depending on one external module (for example Restangular).

I don't know why, but I can not get it working. I'm getting get this kind of error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/unpr?p0=restangularProvider%20%3C-%20restangular
```

Actually, it doesn't matter that it's restangular - I've tried it with other modules and the result was analogical.

I have created a plunker that shows my problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZUoDYtd4sVTT7nLpURi?p=preview

But there is not that much code - I will paste it here too.

In my index.html file I include angular.js, lodash.js (required by restangular), restangular.js and my application's script.js files with  tags.

This is the body of my html:

```
<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <p>Take a look into console... Restangular can not get injected. What am I doing wrong?</p>
</body>
```

And this is the content of script.js:

```
var app = angular.module( 'example', ['restangular'])

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
    console.log(Restangular);
}]);
```

As a note - in the console I can do this:

```
angular.module('restangular')
```

but, this does not work:

```
angular.injector(["ng"]).get('restangular')
```

It seems that I'm missing something basic about Angular.js. Help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be this?

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
```

Restangular hast to be written with a capital R
You wrote

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
```

At least now I see in the console

```
URL visited /edit/3ZUoDYtd4sVTT7nLpURi
editor-0.7.30.js 
Object { configuration={...}, requestParams={...}, defaultHeaders={...}, more...}
```

Comment: Yes, it was indeed this issue. I find it a bit misleading that while declaring my module I have to declare this dependency like this: ['Restangular'], but than later in a controller in this way: ['restangular'].